# consolidate thousands of files with ln

Tags: bash

I am working on a Mac computer using Bash commands via terminal.

I have ~200 directories numbered 0-200.  Each directory contains >5,000 individual files ending in .fast5.  I am trying to figure out the simplest way to consolidate all files from within the group of 200 directories into one directory named Consolidatedfiles.

I have been trying different approaches but none have worked.  The following command was the closest that I think I have come.

```
find ./* -iname "*fast.5" | xargs -I {} ln ./Consolidatedfiles {}
```

However am I messing up the ln command? I have 0 experience pairing `find` to other commands using `xargs`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  My mistake... I meant to write that i would like to collect the files into a single directory.  I corrected this in the question above.

Comment: and one more question: All old files should be moved to the new directory OR just copied?

Comment: Rather than move or copy the files i though that linking to the original files from the new directory using ln would be the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is the **most efficient solution** for creating hard links to all your files in a single target directory<sup>[1]</sup>
, assuming you can use the ***GNU* `ln`**, **which macOS does NOT come with** (you can, however, install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)):

```
find ./* -iname "*fast.5" -exec ln -t ./Consolidatedfiles/ {} +
```

**macOS** allows an efficient **`xargs` solution with `-J`** (BSD-specific), which allows defining a placeholder that expands to (typically) *all* arguments, combined with `-0` and `find -print0` to robustly pass the filenames:

```
find ./* -iname "*fast.5" -print0 | xargs -0 -J {} ln {} ./Consolidatedfiles/
```

A **POSIX-compliant solution** that is **much slower**, because it invokes `ln` for each and every file:

```
find ./* -iname "*fast.5" -exec ln {} ./Consolidatedfiles/ \;
```

Note how **`find`'s `-exec` is like a built-in `xargs`, only more robust as well as more efficient** (because no pipeline and separate `xargs` process are needed):

- `find ... -exec ... {} +` is like piping to `| xargs ...`:

  - (typically) *all* arguments (as many as fit on a single command line, using as few invocations as possible overall) are passed *at once*, invariably at the *end* of the specific command.
  - Note that `{}` *must* be the last argument before `+`, meaning that the filenames can only be passed at the *end* of the command line.

    - This is why *GNU* `ln` is required above, because only it - as an extension to the [POSIX spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html) - allows specifying the target directory *before* the list of file operands, with `-t <dir>`.
- `find ... -exec ... {} ... \;` is like piping to `| xargs -I {} ... {} ...`:

  - The target command is invoked *once for each file*, in the position indicated with `{}`.
- Using `-exec` is also more *robust* than `xargs`, because filenames are always passed correctly, with no concerns regarding filenames with spaces, quotes, or even embedded newlines.

  - By contrast, `xargs` by default breaks the input stream into arguments by whitespace, and using only POSIX-compliant options you cannot guarantee that all arguments are passed correctly; combining `find -print0` with `xargs -0` works robustly, however, and both these nonstandard options are supported on both Linux (GNU utilities) and macOS/BSD. <sup>Thanks, [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy).</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your **`ln` operands are in the wrong order**; the `ln` syntax is:

```
ln <original> <link>
```

so you should have used `ln {} ./Consolidatedfiles/`

With that correction your command should work, but using the `-exec`-based commands above is preferable for reasons of efficiency.

---

<sup>[1] *Hard* links (as opposed to the *symbolic* links created with `ln -s`) are rarely used anymore, but they are useful for safely *moving* files in 2 stages: Hard links point to the exact same data on disk as the original files (in fact, even the original files are hard links), so once you've made sure that the hard links were correctly created in the target location, you can safely delete the original files (whose contents aren't lost, because the new hard links still point to them).</sup>

Comment: There is also a pretty efficient Perl version that avoids creating one process per file... `find ... -print0 | perl -n0e 'ln ...'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I assume you meant `link` (Perl function) rather than `ln` - that is an option, but it requires more work, because `link` doesn't accept a target _directory_ as the 2nd argument.
Turns out that on macOS combining `find -print0` with `xargs -0 -J {}` is probably the best choice - see my update.